# Porque explode muestra los resultados anteriores en un while php

Tags: php, while, explode

Realizo un explode dentro de un while para separar palabras con una coma (,) y arreglarla para que se pueda poner en una consulta sql, en la primera muestra del while sale correctamente lo que quiero pero en el segundo recorreido del while muestra las palabras de la salida anterior:

```
$queryselectprocesses ="SELECT * FROM laziness_config_processes WHERE busid = $buss ";
$execqueryselectprocesses = sqlsrv_query($con_laziness, $queryselectprocesses);

while($fila = sqlsrv_fetch_array($execqueryselectprocesses,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
$modalities_select = $fila['modalities'];
$institutions_select = $fila['institutions'];
```

#el resultado en la primera salida del while de **$modalities_select** = AB, CD

#el resultado en la primera salida del while de **$institutions_select** = CARRO, MOTO

#el resultado en la segunda salida del while de **$modalities_select** = FG, HI

#el resultado en la segunda salida del while de **$institutions_select** = BICICLETA, CASCO

```
$queryselectprocesses ="SELECT * FROM laziness_config_processes WHERE busid = $buss ";
$execqueryselectprocesses = sqlsrv_query($con_laziness, $queryselectprocesses);

while($fila = sqlsrv_fetch_array($execqueryselectprocesses,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
$modalities_select = $fila['modalities'];
$institutions_select = $fila['institutions'];

$mods = explode(',', $modalities_select);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($mods); $i++){
    $mods[$i] = trim($mods[$i]);
}
foreach ($mods as $value) {
    if ($value != '-1' and trim($value) != '') {
        $mod .= "'" . trim($value). "',";
    }
}
if (trim($mod) != '') {
    $mod = substr($mod, 0, strlen($mod)-1);
    $mod = " modality in ( $mod ) ";
}

$insts = explode(',', $institutions_select);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($insts); $i++){
    $insts[$i] = trim($insts[$i]);
}
foreach ($insts as $value) {
   if ($value != '-1' and trim($value) != '') {
        $inst .= "'" . trim($value). "',";
   }
}
if (trim($inst) != '') {
    $inst = substr($inst, 0, strlen($inst)-1);
    $inst = " institution in ( $inst ) ";
}

$query = " select * from tb_model where $mod and $inst ";
echo $query;

}
```

#El resultado en la primera salida del while de $query = select * from tb_study where modality in ( 'AB','CD' ) and institution in ( 'CARRO','MOTO' )

#**PERO** el resultado en la segunda salida del while de $query = select * from tb_study where modality in ( modality in ( 'AB','CD' ) 'FG','HI' ) and institution in ( institution in ( 'CARRO','MOTO' ) 'BICICLETA','CASCO' )

#El resultado que deberia salir en la segunda salida del while de $query = select * from tb_study where modality in ( 'FG','HI' ) and institution in ( 'BICICLETA','CASCO' )

Comment: Los últimos tres enunciados son frases sin predicado. No se entiende lo que preguntas

Answer (score 0):

Se resolvió añadiéndolo al inicio del while, así:

```
while($fila = sqlsrv_fetch_array($execqueryselectprocesses,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
     $mod = '';
     $inst = '';
```

Gracias.